# Search a Table for Customers, display the record in a Form that holds customer records; if no records exist for that customer, create new

Tags: vba, ms-access

[image]

In the Combo” Mandant_Suche“  I’m filling a Variable and search the Table
“Abgabe Unterlagen” for a matching name and display the record.

If it doesn’t exist, the user should get an info msg, the form should have all entries blanked out and a new record should open to allow the user to enter data for a new customer record .

```
Private Sub MandantenSuche_AfterUpdate()

' Den mit dem Steuerelement übereinstimmenden Datensatz suchen.    
 Me.Filter = "Mandant_Nummer_F = " & Me.MandantenSuche  
 Me.FilterOn = True

End Sub
```

this doesn't work properly as some data remain in the form when the user had entered data before.

Also the search doesn't work properly as some records won't display

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of filtering, you can use FindFirst. If something is found, the record will be the active one. You can check with "NoMatch" if a record was found. If not, you can display a message and go to a new record. Here an example:

```
Private Sub Mandant_Suche_AfterUpdate()
    Me.Recordset.FindFirst "Mandant_Nummer_F = " & Mandant_Suche
       If Me.Recordset.NoMatch Then
          MsgBox "Nichts gefunden. Bitte neu eingeben.", vbInformation
          DoCmd.GoToRecord , , acNewRec
       End If
    End Sub
```

Comment: This will work, thank you for your input...I just need to find a way to this also from the Combo which contains the "Mandant_Name"
your answer was a big help...